# Calling static Async task from other fragment

Tags: android, static, android-asynctask

I am trying to call Async task in some other activity from a fragment. I tried to call various way but none of it worked. I just want to know whats the best way to call static AsyncTask .Here is my Async task:

```
static class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    Context context;
    String username, password;
    private MyAsync(Context context, String username, String password) {
        this.context = context;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    private String response;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Connecting to Server","Getting Credentials"
                , true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {       
        try {               
                ContentDownload download = new ContentDownload();
                response = download.loginApi(agentId, password);
                 if(response.contains("Success")){
                     if(SettingHelper.getFirstCall(context)){
                         ContentDownload.CallApi(context);
                         SettingHelper.setFirstCall(context, false);
                     }
                     if(SettingHelper.getFirstLaunch(context)){
                         ContentDownload load = new ContentDownload();
                         load.callItemApi(context);
                         load.callActionApi(context);
                         SettingHelper.setFirstLaunch(context, false);
                     }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(response.contains("Success")){
         context.startActivity(new Intent(context, AllActivity.class));
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Got back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    dialog.dismiss();
}}
```

I am trying to call it this way:

```
      LoginActivity.new MyAsync(getActivity).execute();
```

but its giving error

Comment: You call it the exact same way, why would there be a difference? I suggest you learn java before attempting to write an app. Try this: `new LoginActivity.MyAsync(getActivity()).execute();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It you want to use this class from your `Fragment`, give it public visibility, also a public constructor and then you can call it:

```
new LoginActivity.MyAsync(getActivity())
```